# Correct way to test Django clean form methods with pytest

Tags: pytest, pytest-django

I have a `clean_email` method where I change the input of email field to lowercase to avoid duplicity problems with case-sensitive.

### What I have

#### form

```py
class UserAdminCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("username", "email", "names", "last_names", "identification_number")
    
    def clean_email(self) -> str:
        """Convert all username to lowercase to avoid duplicity problems with case-sensitive."""
        email = self.cleaned_data["email"]
        return email.lower()
```

#### Test

```py
class TestUserCreationForm:
    def test_clean_email(self):
        proto_user = UserFactory.build()  # User created with factory boy.

        form = UserAdminCreationForm(
            {
                "username": proto_user.username,
                "email": proto_user.email,
                "names": proto_user.names,
                "last_names": proto_user.last_names,
                "identification_number": proto_user.identification_number,
            }
        )

        assert form.is_valid()
        assert form.clean_email() == form.cleaned_data["email"].lower()
```

### The problem

Although the test passes, when I generate the coverage report the statement `return email.lower()` from `clean_email` method is showed as untested.

Comment: Have you checked that the code is reached (using a debugger or print)? This looks like a coverage problem to me, not a problem with the code.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen I don't know what happend but sometimes the coverage report change the coverage percentage and sometimes show some lines as untested and other one as 97 or 100% coverage... I dont change anything in my tests.

Comment: That sounds quite strange. From your code it is clear that the line in question should be covered, but different coverage results after executing the same test is something I don't understand - you have nothing random in your code, as far as I can see...

Comment: @MrBeanBremen I dont know what happend I change my tests after that I create my coverage report and doesn't take the changes immediately, I run it a couple of times and nothing, I have happened to close the IDE(pycharm) or run the test 4 or 5 times and then take the changes. It's really frustrating because I use this report to visualize what parts of my code are missing to test.